# Weird problem with relationships in Laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have something like this in my controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Invoice;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function pay( Invoice $invoice ) {
        $product = $invoice->product;

        return $invoice;
    }
}
```

I'm using Eloquent Relationships and When I return invoice model, Laravel join it with the parent relationship (product)! Why this happening?

Comment: Can you show what your invoice and product models look like? Also, I'm not really sure what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is adding the `product` relationship when you return the invoice is because you are calling the following:

```php
$product = $invoice->product;
```

This is because Laravel is loading the relationship when you call it and storing it with the Invoice model. This is so that if you call `product` again on the same instance of that object it doesn't run another database query.

As a result, it returns the invoice model with the relation it has already loaded. Either don't load the product relationship (depends whether you need it or not) or IIRC you can hide the relation when you return it so it should just return the invoice model. You should be able to do something like this:

```php
return $invoice->makeHidden('product');
```